# How do I save string to session storage in Blazor Server in the _Host.cshtml file

Tags: c#, .net, blazor-server-side

Like the title says, I am wondering how to save strings to session storage in Blazor Server in the _Host.cshtml file to then read them in the other Blazor pages. I am getting data from a LiteDB database. I tries using the Blazored.SessionStorage package, but I got an error, without a direct code?, it just redirected me. This happens when I try to do the right way of putting the await before the line.

```
SessionStorage.SetItemAsync("Title", (homepageObj != null) ? "Working" : "Working");
```

This is the code I try to do so it doen't give me an error. But the problem is, when I try to then read the data just below the saving, it returns as empty. Code for reading the session:

```
var val = SessionStorage.GetItemAsStringAsync("Title");
```

Comment: `GetItemAsStringAsync` is not awaited

Comment: But I cant await, otherwise I get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Session object to store and retrive data from session storage.Try the following code to save the string in the session storage from the _Host.cshtml page.

Example:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
    
    @{
        HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("Title", (homepageObj != null) ? "Working" : "Not Working");
    }
```

To read the data from other blazor pages use the same `HttpContextAccessor` to access the session data.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

@code {
    private string title;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        title = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Title");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but I get this error: InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' has been registered.

Comment: Ok so I registered the service but I still get the error: InvalidOperationException: Session has not been configured for this application or request.

Comment: Ok, I added 2 lines in Program.cs: builder.Services.AddSession(); and app.UseSession();. So now it works thanks ;)